# Memory leak of web worker in Firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, memory-leaks, web-worker

When I running a web worker in firefox,
Worker script :

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    var sBufferData = source buffer of imageData( Uint8ClampedArray )
    var resultBuffer = result buffer of operation( Uint8Array )
    for(...) //double for loop operate
       for(...) //get resultBuffer array

    self.postMessage(resultBuffer);

    resultBuffer = sBufferData = undefined;

    self.close(); //web-worker close itself
}, false);
```

Main script:

```
var imageWorker = new Worker("imageWorker.js");
imageWorker.postMessage(source buffer of imageData);
imageWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    //operation...
    imageWorker.terminate(); //web-worker terminate in main thread
    e.data = imageWorker = undefined;
}
```

My image is a **3246*2448 picture**, when I using the web worker will have a memory leak issue in FireFox.

It took **average 200MB** each time to process one image.
After that, FireFox will **keep the 200MB** memory occupation.

Therefore it takes 200MB to every processing until **out of memory**.

**Only Firefox** has the problem. Why it don't release memory? I don't get it. Any idea?

Comment: GC problems with [long-running Web Workers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654265)

Comment: Fix in firefox version 29.